# DbContext vs. DataServicesContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I am working on an existing application that uses an OData (Entity Framework 6.1) WCF service.  I am attempting to scrap the service and reference the Entity Framework project in the solution.  I was making good progress until I started getting errors Like:

1. AddReleatedObject method not found.
2. Table specific methods, like AddTo were not found.

Checking into the class definitions, I find that the main Entity class derives from global::System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.  Looking at the Entity Framework solution that is the basis for the service, the main Entity class derives from System.Data.Entity.DbContext.

Is it possible for me to scrap the service and reference the EF project in the solution without having to change existing code?

EDIT:  Since people are looking and not commenting, maybe I should explain a bit further.  I need to somehow cast the DbContext as a DataServiceContext so these methods will still work.  Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: They're different things, one is intended for communicating with a service across the internet (or local network) and one is intended for communicating directly with a database.  I don't understand why you think they can or should be interchangeable?

Comment: Well, here's the thing.  I create a context object that represents the database.  Using the "service" object, I'm allowed to use syntax similar to:  dbContext.AddToAddresses(....).  Using the standard DbContext object, I am not.  This seems a bit odd to me.  Why would the dataservice construct allow this when the object it's based on does not?  There must be something I'm missing.